# Jquery mouseover mouseleave

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-1">I'm div-1</div>
<div id="div-2">I'm div-2</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#div-1").bind('mouseover',function(event){
  $('#div-2').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
});
$('#div-2').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
});
```

My question is : How can I fadeOut the #div-2 If I mouseleave in the #div-1 ?
I'm currently using jquery 1.2.6 and I can't change the version.

**EDIT**

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JUFDA/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### SOLUTION 1 :

You could wrap your elements and add event handlers on that wrapper.
This way you avoid the different elements mousein/mouseout event handlers conflict:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div-1">I'm div-1</div>
    <div id="div-2">I'm div-2</div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#wrapper').hover(
    function(){$('#div-2').stop().fadeIn(100);},
    function(){$('#div-2').stop().fadeOut(100);}
);
```

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/JUFDA/2/

### SOLUTION 2 :

If you have multiple elements on which you want to bind the same event-handlers, you could try something like listening to the event on the whole document and matching the event's target with your selected elements. If the event is targeted on your elements do something (`fadeIn`), else do something else (`fadeOut`) :

```
var el = $("#div-1,#div-2").get();
$(document).bind('mouseover', function(event) {
    var f = el.indexOf(event.target) === -1
        ? 'fadeOut'
        : 'fadeIn';
    $('#div-2').stop(true, true)[f](100);
});
```

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/JUFDA/1/

I know this is not the optimal solution, but it might come in handy if you want to extend your functionality over other dom elements as well.

### SOLUTION 3 :

You could delay the execution of your `mouseleave` event handler on the first div, this way allowing the event handlers to execute in a different order :
from :

1. `$('#div-1').mouseleave()`
2. `$('#div-2').mouseover()`
   to :
3. `$('#div-2').mouseover()`
4. `$('#div-1').mouseleave()`
   In this way you avoid the event-handlers conflict and, because the animation duration is very little (0.1 seconds), the delay on the first div's `mouseleave` event handler execution is not noticeable :

`$("#div-1")
    .bind('mouseover',function(event){
        $('#div-2').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
    })
    .bind('mouseleave',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!$('#div-2').data('over_second'))
                 $('#div-2').stop(true,true).fadeOut(50);
        },50);
    });
$('#div-2')
    .bind('mouseover',function(event){
        $(this)
            .stop(true,true)
            .fadeIn(100)
            .data('over_second',true);
    })
    .bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $(this)
            .stop(true,true)
            .fadeOut(100)
            .removeData('over_second');
    });`

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/JUFDA/3/

Comment: Thanx for your answer but they are no solution to hide #div-2 I focus #div-1 ? sorry for my poor english ...

Comment: Good job ! But I just want to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JUFDA/4/ without blinking the div-2

Comment: nice solution, however backward traversal causes an "artifact". when moving from div2 to div1 it flickers reinitiating the rule. this is why a wrapper element is advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div-1").bind('mouseover',function(event){
  $(this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
  $('#div-2').fadeOut(100);
});
$('#div-1').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).fadeOut(100);
  $('#div-2').fadeIn(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div-1").bind('mouseover',function(event){
  $('#div-2').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(event){
  $('#div-2').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
});
$('#div-2').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
});
```